# Adding multiple columns to spark dataframe

Tags: pyspark, dataframe

I would like to add several columns to a spark (actually pyspark) dataframe , these columns all being functions of several input columns in the df. There seems to be no 'add_columns' in spark, and add_column while allowing for a user-defined function doesn't seem to allow multiple return values - so does anyone have  a recommendation how I would accomplish this? I'd prefer only calling the generating function d,e,f=f(a,b,c) once per row, as its expensive.

Comment: Have a look [here for some ideas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33681487/how-do-i-add-a-new-column-to-a-spark-dataframe-using-pyspark). They are generally only adding single columns, but perhaps you can make that do what you require.

Comment: [this](https://p058.github.io/spark/2017/01/08/spark-dataframes.html) would seem to be  pretty close tho more involved than what i was hoping for

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35322764/apache-spark-assign-the-result-of-udf-to-multiple-dataframe-columns

Comment: You can create an udf function, and return a dictionary, to this is needed define the struct of the dict, an implemented solution of this method is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32196207/1560062)

Comment: ironic, that this hit 10K views and is off-topic